# Spring Framework Architecture

Tags: spring

Can anyone suggest a good resource for learning Spring framework. Also in Spring Tool Suite how is pivotal Server different from tomcat Server?

Comment: Opinion-based questions are not this forum topic. Please provide, what you have already researched. Have you even googled?

Answer (score 1):

The best resource for Spring is to read the documentation (maybe skip the AOP part to begin with). I did it when version 2.5 came out, and again with version 4. It is probably the best open source documentation out there. It is also some of the best open source code I have read, when I get a spring related exception, I look at the call stack and the code before I ask on stack overflow - In the end you will learn a lot by observing how good frameworks are built.

I have not used Pivotal, but to me it sounds like they have taken the open source TC and made it more Enterprise friendly by adding some management features. I have used Tomcat for the last 13 years, and have never needed it.

Today a lot of applications embed the webserver instead of deploying on a webserver. This is the Spring Boot approach, typically in a combination with Docker or other container technologies, so you can deploy new versions of the application continuously.

There are several good spring boot tutorials out there, if you have not worked with spring before there is a lot of magic under-the-hood, but all the default are very sensible so it is easy to get started. However when something doesn't work, it may take some time to debug, so I recommend that you use git and commit frequently in the beginning so you can go back to something you know works.

The docker/boot approach is great if your application doesn't have state in memory (but in a DB). If you have state (for instance persistent socket connections), that can't be transferred to a new server during deployment, you may want to use an actual Tomcat/application server, so you can have multiple versions of the same application running concurrently. That way existing sessions will continue to use the old version of your application, and new sessions will see the new version, tomcat will automatically undeploy older versions when the last sessions is closed. We use both Boot applications and multi version Tomcats for our projects depending on the requirements, but everything runs on AWS ECS managed docker.

I don't use STS for my Spring development, I have used IntelliJ for as long as I have used Tomcat. Unfortunately the free Community Edition of IntelliJ does not have the nice Spring and Tomcat integrations. Although I have access to IntelliJ at work, I gladly pay 100 EUR a year for my own version so I can code at home. At work we used to have 3 developers that used Eclipse, now we have 0 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot is a more opinionated Spring that lets you deploy an executable JAR without a Java EE app   Server or servlet/JSP engine. It has Jetty embedded inside as an HTTP listener.

The best place to learn is the Spring.io guides.